# A regular expression to validate .NET time format

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex, vb.net

**Background**

I need to validate user input in some fields, where these are defining how to show time in some views.

**Requirements**

Time format must be expressed in Microsoft .NET way *(check this MSDN Library article if you want to learn more about framework's date and time formatting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)*

Keep in mind I'm looking to validate **the format** instead of an actual time string.

For example, user may input:

- HH:mm
- hh:mm
- ss
- hh:ss
- mm:ss
- ... and so on.

In fact, it should validate from the shortest to longest time format available.

Another point is **I need to do it in client-side using JavaScript**. In other words, any given regular expression by you should work in browsers JavaScript regular expressions' engine.

I'll appreciate any self-taylored one, any link or pasted expression!

Thank you in advance.

**NOTE (Update)**

*I can't use ASP.NET validation engine, or any other. Because of project's requirements, I need to avoid that.*

Comment: Just a small clarification, but you want only validation correct? Output is a boolean?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?  This isn't the place to come and ask for solutions to problems and expect people to do it for you.

Comment: HH:mm hh:mm hh:ss mm:ss these are all `2digits:2digits` and not much possibility to distinguish this with regex. Besides the time format hh:ss doesn't make a lot sence...

Comment: I assume you are using asp.net? So you can use a RegularExpressionValidator control

Comment: @bw_üezi He said he's only looking to validate a format. i.e. User is inputting `hh:mm` or `mm:ss` and they will return true, but if user inputs `ss:hh` it returns false, to the best of my understanding.

Comment: @inTide, `10:10` is it `HH:mm` or `mm:ss`?

Comment: @Ramhound Calm, I'm not a regular expression expert and I don't expect you to do my work, but give me an existing work. I don't like reinventing wheels. And creating absolutely accurate and stable regular expressions isn't always an easy task. You know that.

Comment: @polishchuk Since digits aren't a valid time format it'll return false, I don't know why it matters whether it's `HH:mm` or `mm:ss`. The user is inputting a format for the time, not an actual time. No one is inputting `12:30` or if they do it's not valid, they're inputting a format they want their time to be displayed in (presumably, likely another application) Please read the bolded part in the question again.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Right, I'm using ASP.NET, but I won't using any ASP.NET validation engine in this project (it's too complex to deeply explain here that, but it's a client-server architecture that must work all together in a transparent way - I know, it's not a good clarification, but if I need to do it rightly, I should use my blog instead of SO haha).

Comment: @inTide:  ss:hh is a valid time format.  It may not make much sense, but it is valid.  I can easily write DateTime.Now.ToString("ss:hh") and it will work correctly.  If there is a list of valid formats, then the OP could put them in a list and just check them.

Comment: @FOR ALL I don't need to validate invalid ways of express time, I only need to validate that format string is correct. If user inputs "ss:HH" isn't my problem, it's not "a valid time format", but it's a "valid time format string".

Comment: @Chris Ah, you're right, that actually makes this quite easy.

Comment: @Allov I've updated my question so it'll be no more confusion about using ASP.NET validation engine. I **must** avoid it, we can discuss the reasons, but I beileve SO isn't the place for that :D

Comment: @Matías, `#s` or `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!hh` is it valid format?

Comment: Supporting all the myriad formats is going to be very error prone and tricky. I would suggest to restrict them to one or two known formats and build a regexp for that. Something like `^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$` (time in 24 hrs format with optional seconds)

Comment: @polishchuk This isn't a valid format.

Comment: @Mrchief I expect to validate **the format**, not the time value string.

Comment: If you ever come back to this, a cleaner answer than the accepted would be to first make sure no letters are repeated (case insensitive) if they are separated by a colon with a look ahead, then check from `^` or `:`  to `:` or `$` that the the valid letters (`h, s, ... etc`) repeat within the delimiters (i.e. you don't want `hs:hs`) and doesn't go over their own limits (e.g. `h{1,2}` for hours, 2 `h`'s max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, there is no much options - sort of 20, as maximum. Why not just enumerate them all in one big regex without much special symbols? Like

```
'hh:mm|hh:mm:ss|yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm|<etc>'
```

you could than make it case sensitive to differentiate between `M` for month and `m` for minute, and for hours make it `[hH]`, then make it `[:-/]` there where you allow for different separators, and lots of other similar things. But the main idea is to simply enumerate all options separated by `|` with just little amount of regex syntax between `|` and `|`.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first idea to solve this problem, but I was wondering if there's some other way of doing that. By the way, It's about time formatting only, I don't need date-time format.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer: it is even easier, if it is only time. I really think you need to just enumerate them all then.

Comment: I believe you're right. Better than nothing, or something more: the best way to achieve this result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of a "valid" format string?  Only once you know that can it be possible to validate a format string.

"K" is also a valid format string

"zz" is also a valid format string

"e" is also a valid format (it would fall into the "The character is copied to the result string unchanged." case)

I'm not even sure what formats would actually cause .NET .ToString() to throw an exception (if that's what you are trying to avoid).

Comment: I believe that this would be better discussed in question's comments. By the way, read them, as I've answered same thoughts to others.